# schroot: pass a command to be executed as if it's in a shell

Tags: linux, unix

i want to do something like:

```
schroot -c name -u root "export A=3 && export B=4"
```

but i get the error:

```
Failed to execute “export”: No such file or directory
```

In other words, I want to be able to programmatically execute shell commands inside the schroot environment. What is the right way to get this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

schroot bash -c "export....

Answer (score 1):

an echo solution is possible as :

```
echo "export A=3 && export B=4" | schroot -c name -u root
```

I use this behavior for a svn/git buildpackaging bash

Answer (score 0):

I think since export is a shell builtin that you'd need do do `bash export` for that to work. Try it again but with a real command.